# Is it safe to fill CompleteMultipartUpload() parts list with ListParts() result?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

on `CompleteMultipartUpload` API we have to put the list of uploaded parts E-tags.

I saw that `ListParts` result is not the same as my app state about parts. all of my `UploadPart` calls don't have any error but Sometimes the `ListParts` misses some of them.

So, is it right to fill these E-tags by the result of `ListParts` API result? If not, why the results are not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not safe** to use the `ListParts` response data when calling `CompleteMultipartUpload`.  Doing so can mask problems in your code.

> Only use the returned listing for verification. You should not use the result of this listing when sending a complete multipart upload request. Instead, maintain your own list of the part numbers you specified when uploading parts and the corresponding ETag values that Amazon S3 returns.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

`ListParts` is only intended for sanity checking, for comparison.  You need to use the etags you received when uploading the original parts.  If the `ListParts` response is incomplete, that may only be an eventual consistency issue in S3 and a subsequent poll may return the apparently-missing parts.  If the `ListParts` response is actually in conflict with what you received when uploading the parts, there is a problem with your code or corruption on the wire or (unlikely) inside S3.

A multipart upload client has no need for the `ListParts` action.